# screenshotting urls with node - async

Tags: node.js

Here is my code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const screenshot = require('screenshot-stream');
const urlp = require('url');
var urls=[
'https://archive.org/details/8bitrecs',
'http://hackaday.com/',
'http://techcrunch.com/2012/02/16/auraslate-is-an-open-source-android-tablet-for-hackers/',
'http://www.english.illinois.edu/-people-/faculty/debaron/482/482readings/greenfield.html',
'http://sustain.rca.ac.uk/Sustain-Talks'];
urls.forEach(function(url){
    const stream = screenshot(url, '1024x768', {crop: true});
    stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(urlp.parse(url).hostname + 'test-1024x768.png')); 
});
```

It only screenshots the last item in the url. Rhe others are images with zero bytes. I think I need to do the operation asynchronously so it doesn't overwrite the stream each time.

How would I do this?

UPDATE: 
I want the screenshot to work, but catch errors and not block if a url is not accessible

UPDATE:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/screenshot-promise worked better although this code below still slows my computer down a lot!

```
const screenshotPromise = require('screenshot-promise');
```

...

```
urls.forEach(function(url) {



const promise = screenshotPromise(url, '1024x768', {crop: true}).then(buf => {
    fs.writeFileSync(urlp.parse(url).hostname + 'test-1024x768.png', buf);
});


promise.then((value) => {
  // value is whatever we passed in the resolve(...) function above.
  // It doesn't have to be a string, but if it is only a succeed message, it probably will be.
  console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: Where is the variable `stream` is defined?

Comment: const stream = screenshot(url, '1024x768', {crop: true});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you failed to add here is the error :

> events.js:160
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> Error: Couldn't load url: http://techcrunch.com/2012/02/16/auraslate-is-an-open-source-android-tablet-for-hackers/
>       at LineStream.byline.on.data
>    (e:---\node_modules\screenshot-stream\index.js:77:16)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at LineStream.emit (events.js:188:7)

The issue is that the module `screenshot-stream` is using PhantomJS, and phantomJS is unable to get to the page that outputs the error.

This error seems related to this issue : https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10460.

> Techcrunch.com and Aol.com seem to use web fonts (e.g. "BebasNeue-webfont.ttf") which Qt loads as application fonts. Something may be going wrong there.

My suggestion is using Google's Puppeteer that includes a built-in screenshot method : https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagescreenshotoptions

Comment: google puppeteer looks like probably a nicer option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Code I did in the end that worked:

```
   const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const urlp = require('url');
var URL = require('url-parse');
var urls = [
    'https://archive.org/details/8bitrecs',
    'http://hackaday.com/',
    'http://techcrunch.com/2012/02/16/auraslate-is-an-open-source-android-tablet-for-hackers/',
    'http://www.english.illinois.edu/-people-/faculty/debaron/482/482readings/greenfield.html',
    'http://sustain.rca.ac.uk/Sustain-Talks',
    'https://www.quintessentially.com/',
    'https://www.producthunt.com/tech/ux-project-checklist',
    'https://freedom.press/',
    'http://issuu.com/search?q=vintage+motorcycle',
    'http://www.pocketmod.com/v2/',
    'https://www.metamind.io/',
    'http://nautil.us/blog/chernobyls-hot-mess-the-elephants-foot-is-still-lethal',
    'https://www.instructables.com/id/Tool-Storage-Hacks-or-How-to-Hang-Those-Black-Frid/',
    'https://www.zippi.co.uk/framed-photo-print'
];
var getLocation = function(href) {
    var l = document.createElement("a");
    l.href = href;
    return l;
};
(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    page.waitForNavigation({
        timeout: 40000
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        const url = urls[i];
        var url1 = new URL(url);
        try {
            await page.goto(`${url}`);
            await page.screenshot({
                path: 'images/' + url1.hostname + '.png'
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
            // await page.close();
            // await browser.close();
            // process.exit(1);
            continue;
        }
    }
})();
```